# Creating product images programmatically and exclude them from gallery?

Tags: product, product-images

I am creating products with code and I am also adding images. This is the code:

```
$mediaArray = array(
    'thumbnail'   => $mainImage,
    'small_image' => $mainImage,
    'image'       => $mainImage,
);

foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName) {
     $filePath = $fileName;
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        try {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false, true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works, but they are not excluded from the gallery images. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $mediaArray = array(
    'thumbnail'   => $mainImage,
    'small_image' => $mainImage,
    'image'       => $mainImage
    );

foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName) {
     $filePath = $fileName;
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        try {
            $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array($imageType), false, true);
            //OR
            // $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('gallery'), false, true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is not working ... any other ideas?